# Algorithm for optimal moves to solve this puzzle

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, shortest-path

There is a mobile puzzle game called Puzzle and Dragons that I'm interested in writing a board solver for, just for fun. It has a 5x6 board where each index holds a random color. It is similar to Bejeweled except you try to build a path in one movement that connects the most gems as possible. You have about 4 seconds to connect gems and you can end it early by letting go of the screen. After letting go, gems that are matched will disappear and gems above it will fall down while new random gems appear from the top.

Here is a demonstration of how the game works: http://www.maaak.net/pad/

I did a little bit of research and found out that I'm dealing with clustering problems here. I want to find the sets of the same color and then try to connect them with other sets of other colors.

Could you help me get started on this algorithm? Am I heading in the right direction? What are some specific clustering algorithms that I can try to incorporate?

Comment: I gather from your (broad, general) questions that you aren't ready to implement an algorithm for it. It'll take more research to narrow down your questions until you have a good grasp of the *problem*. Then a solution will come. But, Graph Theory might help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory

Comment: I'm pretty sure a greedy dfs could do this but there are way too many possibilities and it'll be really slow.

The reason I seem like I don't know anything because I've never tried to create my own project before. I've just been doing school related projects and programming so I've been led along the way every time in the past which is a bad habit.

I've already taken classes like algorithms II (includes graph theory) and most of the upper div classes.

Comment: I didn't (and don't) mean to sound condescending. Frankly, I think the project may be out of your immediate reach, but guess what? Those are the kinds of problems that will refine your talent and hone your skills. (The interesting problems are always too hard. That never changes.) Unfortunately, I'm out of fortune-cookies, and I haven't a clue about a dfs. But, happy hunting!

Comment: I'm positive that I can implement it using a brute force greedy algorithm but my problem is just that brute forcing it would be way too slow. So I'm trying to look for other alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not at all sound like clustering to me.

You may want to look at **graph algorithms** and **constraint solvers** instead.

(I'm not sure what, because I do not understand the "simulator" you linked to at all; it also is too large for my screen.)